# Bendixon-Dulac applied to an extended Lotka Volterra system

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, algebraic-topology

I'm doing the following problem:

> Consider the following system modelling the interaction between two species:
>
> $$\begin{cases}\dot{x}=x(ax^n+by^n+c) \\ \dot{y}=y(dx^n+ey^n+f) \end{cases}$$
>
> with $(a,b,c,d,e,f)\in\mathbb{R^6}$, $n\in\mathbb{N}$. **Find a relation $\phi(a,b,c,d,e,f,n)$** such that:
>
> $i)$ If $\phi(a,b,c,d,e,f,n)\neq 0$, then the system has no periodic orbits. Indication: Prove that you can reduce the problem to the first quadrant, and then use the following Dulac function: $D(x,y)=x^\alpha y^\beta$, with properly $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

I've proved that we can reduce the problem to the first quadrant by seeing that $x=0$ and $y=0$ are orbits of the system, so by uniqueness of solutions, we cannot have a periodic orbit crossing them.

Furthermore, we can change the variables to reduce it to the first quadrant.

Now we have to use the Bendixon-Dulac Theorem, with $B(x,y)$ the function they gave to us. Now the main thing that I don't know how to do is to obtain that relation  $\phi(a,b,c,d,e,f,n)$. I don't know how to get there.

I found the divergence of the Bendixon Dulac theorem but there's a lot of terms and it's really confusing. Do we have to equal it to zero to find the terms $\alpha$ and $\beta$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Bendixson-Dulac needs application only inside each quadrant because $x=0$ and $y = 0$ are orbits.

Now with

$$
\dot x = u(x,y)\\
\dot y = v(x,y)
$$

and defining $\phi(x,y) = x^{\alpha}y^{\beta}$ we have

$$
(\phi(x,y)u(x,y))_x + (\phi(x,y)v(x,y))_y = \phi(x,y) \left(x^n (a \alpha +a n+a+\beta  d+d)+y^n (\alpha  b+b+\beta  e+e n+e)+(\alpha +1) c+(\beta +1) f\right)
$$

Now choosing

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
\alpha & = & \displaystyle -\frac{-a e n-a e+b d+d e n}{b d-a e}\\
\beta  & = &  \displaystyle-\frac{a b n-a e n-a e+b d}{b d-a e}
\end{array}
\right.
$$

from

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
a \alpha +a n+a+\beta  d+d & = & 0\\
\alpha  b+b+\beta  e+e n+e & = & 0
\end{array}
\right.
$$

we get

$$
(\phi(x,y)u(x,y))_x + (\phi(x,y)v(x,y))_y = \phi(x,y)\left(\frac{n (a f (e-b)+c e (a-d))}{b d-a e} \right)
$$

which is non null inside any quadrant, after careful check for the fraction numerator/denominator.

Comment: Thanks a lot Cesar. Hoy did you get that fraction?

Comment: From $$
\left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
a \alpha +a n+a+\beta  d+d & = & 0\\
\alpha  b+b+\beta  e+e n+e & = & 0
\end{array}
\right.
$$